# Problems using pyd files on Sikuli IDE

Tags: jython, pyodbc, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I'm trying to use the pyodbc package on Sikuli IDE, but I'm running into some issues because it seems that Sikuli cannot identify pyd files.

I placed the pyd file in the Sikulix\Lib folder, but when I try to import it, I keep getting the message "No module named pyodbc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with SikuliX (since it is jython/java based) only pure python language modules or modules ported to Jython can be used.

Modules like pyodbc contain C-based stuff or depend on native libs - not posible to use with SikuliX

RaiMan (developer of SikuliX)